# remote postgres user logon with certificate

Tags: postgresql, ssl, configuration

I would like to have each remote user logon using an SSL certificate and use their postgres logon role to better track their use of the system. I can set up a certificate for a given user per the documentation. However, there are many users. Is there a method for configuration using a single certificate, bound to a specific database, that would allow the various users roles to logon?

Comment: Can you point to the documentation please.